# Numpy distutils not recognizing Fortran file types

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, distutils

I am trying to write a python package with Anaconda3 which includes some compiled Fortran libraries. Based on the examples given online, I need to use `numpy.distutils.core.Extension` to have the extension build correctly. Here is my somewhat-minimal working example directory:

```
MANIFEST.in
setup.py
bin
 └─── test_smat
mypkg
 ├─── __init__.py
 ├─── compiled
 |     ├─── __init__.py
 |     └─── gaussian.f90
 └─── pystuff
       ├─── __init__.py
       └─── buildmat.py
```

`MANIFEST.in` contains:

```
recursive-include mypkg *.f90
```

`setup.py` contains:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension


ext_modules = [
    Extension('mypkg.compiled.gaussian',
              sources=['mypkg/compiled/gaussian.f90'])
               ]


setup(
    name='mypkg',
    version='0.1',
    description='This should work',
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts=['bin/test_smat'],
    install_requires=['numpy>=1.7.0'],
    ext_modules = ext_modules
      )
```

`gaussian.f90` contains (EDIT: simplified):

```
!                                                                           
!  Calculates the overlap between two Gaussians                             
!                                                                           
subroutine overlap(x1, x2, a1, a2, S)                                       
    implicit none                                                           
    double precision, intent(in)  :: x1, x2, a1, a2                         
    double precision, intent(out) :: S                                      

    double precision, parameter   :: pi=atan(1.0_8)                         
    double precision              :: N1, N2, dist, expt                     

    N1 = (pi / (2*a1)) ** (-0.75)                                           
    N2 = (pi / (2*a2)) ** (-0.75)                                           
    dist = abs(x2 - x1)                                                     
    expt = a1*a2*dist**2 / (a1 + a2)                                        
    S = N1 * N2 * exp(-expt) * (pi / (a1 + a2)) ** 1.5                      

    return                                                                  
end subroutine overlap
```

`buildmat.py` contains:

```
"""                                                                         
Module for building matrices of Gaussian properties                         
"""                                                                         
import numpy as np                                                          
import mypkg.compiled.gaussian as gaussian                                  


def olap_matrix(x, a):                                                      
    """Builds an overlap matrix from a set of positions and widths."""      
    ngauss = len(x)                                                         
    Smat = np.empty((ngauss, ngauss))                                       

    for i in range(ngauss):                                                 
        for j in range(ngauss):                                             
            Smat[i,j] = gaussian.overlap(x[i], x[j], a[i], a[j])            

    return Smat
```

`test_smat` contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                       
"""                                                                         
Script to test Python modules depending on Fortran libraries.               
"""                                                                         
import mypkg.pystuff.buildmat as buildmat                                   


def main():                                                                 
    """The main routine."""                                                 
    x = [-1, -0.9, -0.5, -0.1, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1]               
    a = [1.2, 0.8, 0.3, 1.5, 3.2, 0.9, 0.8, 0.1, 1.6]                       
    mat = buildmat.olap_matrix(x, a)                                        

    print(mat)                                                              


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                  
    main()
```

Ideally, I should be able to install with `python setup.py install` and run `test_smat` to get a printed output. However, when I try to install I get:

```
running install                                                             
running bdist_egg                                                           
running egg_info                                                            
writing mypkg.egg-info/PKG-INFO                                             
writing dependency_links to mypkg.egg-info/dependency_links.txt             
writing requirements to mypkg.egg-info/requires.txt                         
writing top-level names to mypkg.egg-info/top_level.txt                     
reading manifest file 'mypkg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'                          
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'                                     
writing manifest file 'mypkg.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'                          
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg                     
running install_lib                                                         
running build_py                                                            
creating build                                                              
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6                                         
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mypkg                                   
copying mypkg/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mypkg               
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mypkg/pystuff                           
copying mypkg/pystuff/buildmat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mypkg/pystuff
copying mypkg/pystuff/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mypkg/pystuff
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mypkg/compiled                          
copying mypkg/compiled/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/mypkg/compiled
running build_ext                                                           
building 'mypkg.compiled.gaussian' extension                                
C compiler: gcc -pthread -B /home/rymac/.anaconda3/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC

error: unknown file type '.f90' (from 'mypkg/compiled/gaussian.f90')
```

Am I missing something that tells NumPy distutils that the extension is a Fortran 90 file? Other examples on this website seem to have a `setup.py` file that is just as simple without encountering this error. Changing the Fortran extension to `.f95` or `.f` leads to the same type of error.

Comment: Does NumPy recognize that you have a Fortran 90 compiler? I'm pretty sure there's a function named something like `has_f90c` you can call to check.)

Comment: Oops, it's `have_f90c`, not `has`. See [DISTUTILS.txt](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/DISTUTILS.rst.txt).

Comment: Assuming f2py sees the same environment as the rest of numpy, it should. I can compile `gaussian.f90` in place with `f2py -c -m gaussian gaussian.f90`

Comment: But that assumption is exactly what we need to rule out. It’s possible that f2py can find your f90 compiler but numpy distutils can’t. If so, that’s what we need to debug. If not, we have to look for the problem elsewhere. If you just add the call and see what it says, we’ll know one way or the other.

Comment: It was apparently a problem with using `setuptools.setup` instead of `numpy.distutils.core.setup`. The install runs properly now, but there seems to be an additional problem with the test script `bin/test_smat`.

Comment: If you solved your original problem and now have a completely different problem, don't change this into a completely different question. Either write and accept an answer, if you think it will be useful to anyone else (asuming you can explain it well, but I'm pretty sure you can), or ask for this one to be closed. And then write a new question about your new problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in trying to use `setuptools.setup` with `numpy.disutils.core.Extension`. The numpy version of `Extension` contains additional information about `f2py` that isn't included in `setuptools.Extension`, but this can only be used to build Fortran libraries if `numpy.distutils.core.setup` is used as well.

The solution: replace `from setuptools import setup` with `from numpy.distutils.core import setup` in `setup.py`.